# Javascript hard validation

Tags: javascript, validation, concatenation, modulo

I'm trying to implement a specific validation (the BBAN validtion).

I have to validate one field with 3 other fields. I explain:

I have the first part of the code: (they all are input type=text and the follogines are their respective names) establishmentCode, bankCode, accountNumber. They all are numbers and into three differents fields.

The last field (that must be validated) will validate others fields:

```
97 - (concat(establishmentCode, bankCode, accountNumber)*100 % 97  )
```

How can i Concat those fields??? Can I multiply something that i concat (do I have to pass the concated string into one int before applying a modulo?

Thanks to help me :-)

**EDIT**

```
var goodkey = 97 - ( (parseInt (String(establishment) + String(bank) + String(account)) *100 % 97 ) );
            alert(goodkey);
            if (document.myForm.key.value != goodkey ) {
                document.myForm.establishment.style.backgroundColor="red";
        alert("The key must be " + goodkey);
                return false;
            }
```

Comment: Could you post your code please?

Answer (score 0):

You probably mean to do something like this:

```
var val = 97 - (
          parseInt (String(establishmentCode) + String(bankCode) 
                                + String(accountNumber)) *100 % 97  )
alert(val);
```

The question is: when you use "%" - you mean reminder or percent ?

Comment: I checked it and it does! what is the result you're expecting ? did you notice the last line I wrote ?